# Get JSON array length based on its attribute value

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

How to get JSON array length efficiently in jquery based on its attribute value.

for example array is:

```
var arr = [{
    "name":"amit",
    "online":true
},{
    "name":"rohit",
    "online":false
},{
    "name":"kk",
    "online":true
},{
    "name":"mohit",
    "online":true
},];
```

I want to get online users length i.e where `online = true`.

Comment: let us know what you have tried

Comment: You would need to loop over the object and count the number of objects with that property value. Better yet, assuming this JSON is coming from a server, change the endpoint to only return the users where `online = true`

Comment: @sidgate I am asking for the efficient way.I tried loop.

Comment: @AmitKumar check my answer and fiddle

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Length of a JavaScript object (that is, associative array)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5223/length-of-a-javascript-object-that-is-associative-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)**

Try like this

```
console.log(arr.filter(function(x){ return x.online;}).length)
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ab6kzrn6/1/)

Answer (score 1):

try this using jQuery **grep**

```
  var arr = [
        {"name":"amit",
        "online":true},
        {"name":"rohit",
        "online":false},
        {"name":"kk",
        "online":true},
        {"name":"mohit",
        "online":true},
    ];

 var data =  jQuery.grep(arr, function(obj) {
     return obj.online == true;
 });

    console.log(data.length)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = [{
    "name":"amit",
    "online":true
},{
    "name":"rohit",
    "online":false
},{
    "name":"kk",
    "online":true
},{
    "name":"mohit",
    "online":true
}];
var count = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    if(arr[i].online == true){
        count++
    }
}

console.log(count);
```

Try this way
`you will get 3`